# Why does Pasting or typing in my password and hitting enter creates newlines instead of submitting password?

Tags: password, postgresql, putty

I'm working from a windows computer, and the server that I am renting is from digital ocean using Ubuntu. I am trying to create a postgres db dump, and when I am prompted to enter my password I am having trouble submitting it.

These new lines are happening when I either type it in manually, shift + insert the password, copy and right mouse click. I don't know what to do and I am unable to find any answers. The few people I have asked, they have never had this issue happen before. I am wondering if this issue has to deal with windows pc? A friend of mine is also using windows and having the same issue as me.

To better understand the issue I have included imgur picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJ4S6.png

What in the world is happening? How can I submit the password without it making new lines.

If it helps the password does have special characters randomly generated like # ^ etc. Could this be the issue? I am also using putty for windows to connect and execute the commands.

update: I am also having the same issue when I try to do it through the console on DO.

Answer (score 0):

Hi please enter the below code and try:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

now enter your root password. now you are connected to postgressql 
if you want to change postgres password enter below code in psql

```
\password
```

if you want to change postgres user password enter below code in psql

```
ALTER USER user_name WITH PASSWORD 'new_password';
```

I hope it helps you